# Date stored in a list returning a number in R

Tags: r

Why does date return a number when stored in a list?

```
date <- Sys.Date()

date 
#> "2020-12-18"

list <- c('a', 'b', 2, 3, date)

list
#> "a"     "b"     "2"     "3"     "18614"
```

Anyone knows why it's returning `18614`?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the structure is not a `list`, but a `vector` with `c`.  We need

```
lst1 <- list('a', 'b', 2, 3, date)
```

A `vector` can have only a single type and if there is a single `character` element, the type would be `character`.  Here, the `date` is coerced to its `integer` storage mode.

A `list` can have different types for each of its elements.  Same reason, `data.frame` columns can have different types as `data.frame` is a `list` with columns of equal `length`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know why this happens for vectors?

Comment: @Thomas It is by design the structure allows only a single type